# State Pattern: duplication in State and Context

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, finite-state-machine

Wikipedia gave an example of [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern):

Define `LowerCaseState` and `MultipleUpperCaseState`, both inherite from `State`.

```java
interface State {
    void writeName(StateContext context, String name);
}

class LowerCaseState implements State {
    @Override
    public void writeName(StateContext context, String name) {
        System.out.println(name.toLowerCase());
        context.setState(new MultipleUpperCaseState());
    }
}

class MultipleUpperCaseState implements State {
    /* Counter local to this state */
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void writeName(StateContext context, String name) {
        System.out.println(name.toUpperCase());
        /* Change state after StateMultipleUpperCase's writeName() gets invoked twice */
        if (++count > 1) {
            context.setState(new LowerCaseState());
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have a `Context` class:

```java
class StateContext {
    private State state;

    public StateContext() {
        state = new LowerCaseState();
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state.
     * Normally only called by classes implementing the State interface.
     * @param newState the new state of this context
     */
    void setState(State newState) {
        state = newState;
    }

    public void writeName(String name) {
        state.writeName(this, name);
    }
}
```

The usage will be:

```java
public class StateDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StateContext context = new StateContext();

        context.writeName("Monday");
        context.writeName("Tuesday");
        context.writeName("Wednesday");
        context.writeName("Thursday");
        context.writeName("Friday");
        context.writeName("Saturday");
        context.writeName("Sunday");
    }
}
```

Noted that both the `State` interface and `StateContext` have a `writeName()` method. If we add more methods like that, say, `writePoem()`, `writeCode()`, `writeEssay()`, etc, we have to add them twice, once in `State`, and onece in `StateContext`.

What the `writeName()` method in `StateContext` is merely propergate the "write name" request, or event to the `State`s.

Are there any way to eliminate this dupilication? Or is this usually considered acceptable?

Comment: This is how Composition and interfaces work.  I don't see any problems with your code.

Comment: However, note that this is a contrived example; the the StateContext is *not required* to have the same methods as the state. Generally speaking, StateContext provides operations to be used by client code; these operations depend on the State object internally, and may be realized by calling either some specific operation on the state object, or by some sequence of code that calls several state operations - with the overall effect depending on the current (concrete) state. This depends on how exactly the State abstraction is conceptualized.

Answer (score 1):

Your delegating the functionality to the state object. Its not duplication as you need to expose the functionality somehow and exposing the state object itself would introduce another layer of coupling.